# Is There A Limit to The Number of Observables in .zip Method?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-kotlin

There seems to be a limit to the number of Observables to use as parameters in the zip method for Kotlin. If this is accurate, what is the best alternative?

For instance, when I use 9 parameters it works as expected. When I add a 10th parameter I receive the error **Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly**

```
Observable.zip(
            //TODO: parameterize exchange symbols based on pair
            methodOne() as Observable<Any>),
            methodTwo() as Observable<Any>),
            methodThree() as Observable<Any>),
            methodFour() as Observable<Any>),
            methodFive() as Observable<Any>),
            methodSix() as Observable<Any>),
            methodSeven() as Observable<Any>),
            methodEight() as Observable<Any>),
            methodNine() as Observable<Any>),
            { oneResult, twoResult, threeResult, fourResult, fiveResult, sixResult, sevenResult, eightResult, nineResult ->
                    //logic here applying computation to results
            })
            .subscribe(
                    {},
                    {
                        println(String.format("Error: %s", it.message))
                    })
            .unsubscribe()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RxJava only supports up to 9 distinct sources with `zip`. Beyond that, you have to use the [`zip(Iterable<ObservableSource>, Func<Object[],R>)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#zip-java.lang.Iterable-io.reactivex.functions.Function-) method and cast each element of the `Object[]` back to its respective type.

> Returns an `Observable` that emits the results of a specified `combiner` function applied to combinations of items emitted, in sequence, by an `Iterable` of other `ObservableSource`s.
>   zip applies this function in strict sequence, so the first item emitted by the new `ObservableSource` will be the result of the function applied to the first item emitted by each of the source `ObservableSource`s; the second item emitted by the new `ObservableSource` will be the result of the function applied to the second item emitted by each of those `ObservableSource`s; and so forth.
>
> The resulting `ObservableSource<R>` returned from zip will invoke `onNext` as many times as the number of `onNext` invocations of the source `ObservableSource` that emits the fewest items.
>
> The operator subscribes to its sources in order they are specified and completes eagerly if one of the sources is shorter than the rest while disposing the other sources. Therefore, it is possible those other sources will never be able to run to completion (and thus not calling `doOnComplete()`). This can also happen if the sources are exactly the same length; if source A completes and B has been consumed and is about to complete, the operator detects A won't be sending further values and it will dispose B immediately. For example:
>
> ```
> zip(Arrays.asList(range(1, 5).doOnComplete(action1), range(6, 5).doOnComplete(action2)), (a) -> a)
> ```
>
> `action1` will be called but `action2` won't. 
>   To work around this termination property, use `doOnDispose(Action)` as well or use `using()` to do cleanup in case of completion or a `dispose()` call.
>   Note on method signature: since Java doesn't allow creating a generic array with new `T[]`, the implementation of this operator has to create an `Object[]` instead. Unfortunately, a `Function<Integer[], R>` passed to the method would trigger a `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several overloaded methods `Observable.zip()` and the one with maximum number of `ObservableSource` argument is 9:

```
public static <T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, R> Observable<R> zip(
        ObservableSource<? extends T1> source1, ObservableSource<? extends T2> source2, ObservableSource<? extends T3> source3,
        ObservableSource<? extends T4> source4, ObservableSource<? extends T5> source5, ObservableSource<? extends T6> source6,
        ObservableSource<? extends T7> source7, ObservableSource<? extends T8> source8, ObservableSource<? extends T9> source9,
        Function9<? super T1, ? super T2, ? super T3, ? super T4, ? super T5, ? super T6, ? super T7, ? super T8, ? super T9, ? extends R> zipper) {
```

If you want to have more than 9 sources, take a look at [`zipArray`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#zipArray-io.reactivex.functions.Function-boolean-int-io.reactivex.ObservableSource...-) or [`zipIterable`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#zipIterable-java.lang.Iterable-io.reactivex.functions.Function-boolean-int-)

Answer (score 0):

According to Oracle Java Doc : http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#zip(java.lang.Iterable,%20rx.functions.FuncN)

these methods exist :

```
static <R> Observable<R>    zip(java.lang.Iterable<? extends Observable<?>> ws, FuncN<? extends R> zipFunction)

static <R> Observable<R>    zip(Observable<?>[] ws, FuncN<? extends R> zipFunction)

static <R> Observable<R>    zip(Observable <? extends Observable<?>> ws, FuncN<? extends R> zipFunction)

static <T1,T2,R> Observable<R>  zip(Observable<? extends T1> o1, Observable<? extends T2> o2, Func2<? super T1,? super T2,? extends R> zipFunction)

static <T1,T2,T3,R>
Observable<R>   zip(Observable<? extends T1> o1, Observable<? extends T2> o2, Observable<? extends T3> o3, Func3<? super T1,? super T2,? super T3,? extends R> zipFunction)

static <T1,T2,T3,T4,R>
Observable<R>   zip(Observable<? extends T1> o1, Observable<? extends T2> o2, Observable<? extends T3> o3, Observable<? extends T4> o4, Func4<? super T1,? super T2,? super T3,? super T4,? extends R> zipFunction)

static <T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,R>
Observable<R>   zip(Observable<? extends T1> o1, Observable<? extends T2> o2, Observable<? extends T3> o3, Observable<? extends T4> o4, Observable<? extends T5> o5, Func5<? super T1,? super T2,? super T3,? super T4,? super T5,? extends R> zipFunction)


static <T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,R>
Observable<R>   zip(Observable<? extends T1> o1, Observable<? extends T2> o2, Observable<? extends T3> o3, Observable<? extends T4> o4, Observable<? extends T5> o5, Observable<? extends T6> o6, Func6<? super T1,? super T2,? super T3,? super T4,? super T5,? super T6,? extends R> zipFunction)

static <T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,R>
Observable<R>   zip(Observable<? extends T1> o1, Observable<? extends T2> o2, Observable<? extends T3> o3, Observable<? extends T4> o4, Observable<? extends T5> o5, Observable<? extends T6> o6, Observable<? extends T7> o7, Func7<? super T1,? super T2,? super T3,? super T4,? super T5,? super T6,? super T7,? extends R> zipFunction)

static <T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,R>
Observable<R>   zip(Observable<? extends T1> o1, Observable<? extends T2> o2, Observable<? extends T3> o3, Observable<? extends T4> o4, Observable<? extends T5> o5, Observable<? extends T6> o6, Observable<? extends T7> o7, Observable<? extends T8> o8, Func8<? super T1,? super T2,? super T3,? super T4,? super T5,? super T6,? super T7,? super T8,? extends R> zipFunction)

static <T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,R>
Observable<R>   zip(Observable<? extends T1> o1, Observable<? extends T2> o2, Observable<? extends T3> o3, Observable<? extends T4> o4, Observable<? extends T5> o5, Observable<? extends T6> o6, Observable<? extends T7> o7, Observable<? extends T8> o8, Observable<? extends T9> o9, Func9<? super T1,? super T2,? super T3,? super T4,? super T5,? super T6,? super T7,? super T8,? super T9,? extends R> zipFunction)
```

So to have more than 9 elements use an array or an iterable it will be simplier